# Disabling specific data entry objects based on edit button clicked on GridView row

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a GridView, and I want the user to be able to edit different data in the row depending on which button they click (multiple edit buttons in each row).

For example, if `editButton1` is clicked, and the gridview goes into edit mode,  `dropdownlist1` should be shown and `dropdownlist2` should be hidden. Conversely, if `editButton2` is clicked, `dropdownlist2` should be shown and `dropdownlist1` should be hidden.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle GridView RowEditing event and hide/show the required dropdowns.

Here's an article to get you started : http://devilswork.wordpress.com/2009/03/27/gridview-row-edit-delete-and-update/

And here are the details for row editing event : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting.aspx

**Updated Answer :**

You can use the RowEditing event and use the sender object to get the button identity and hiding accordingly.

If you want to use the Command value then you can use RowCommand event : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx

Your button's command name will be Edit.

Comment: how can i get the command argument value of the control that triggered the postback inside the RowEditing event?

Comment: Editing event doesn't send the information about which button was fired. In that case you would need the Row Command event. Updating my answer.

Comment: i can't seem to access the dropdownlist controls from within the RowCommand event. i populate the command argument of the button with the row number and attempt to access the object with this code: (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowNumber].FindControl("DropDownListJobsTasks"). the dropdownlist objects are in the editItemTemplate.

Comment: In RowCommand event, you can get the row which fired the event from this : GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer); //Assumed that you are using linked button, cast according to the button you used. Try this instead of the line you mentioned and then find drop down.